# Why won't my python program print the list?

Tags: python, selenium, reddit, praw

```
import praw
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

r = praw.Reddit(client_id='XXXXXXXXXX',
                     client_secret='XXXXXXXXXXXXX', password='XXXXXXXXX',
                     user_agent='Grand Street Tech', username='grandstreetsupreme')
subreddit = r.subreddit('supremeclothing')
submissions = []
users = []
for submission in r.subreddit('supremeclothing').new(limit=999):
    for comment in submission.comments:
        author = comment.author
        users.append(author)
```

It takes like 10 minutes to complete and when it does it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Is this your entire code or just a snippet? You're not printing your list `users` anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

There is no print statement for the users right, put a statement like below.

```
print users
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you just created the list `users`, you need to tell python to print it.

After your `for` loop, put `print users`